# How can I schedule a YouTube livestream entirely from Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I have a setup on a Raspberry Pi (with its native camera) that uses a cronjob to start an ffmpeg session with its output streaming to YouTube. I re-use the same stream key each time, which is written into my ffmpeg scripts. This all works perfectly each week, automatically starting and stopping at the desired time.
However, each week PRIOR to that livestream, I have to "manually" go into YouTube Studio and "schedule" a new future event.  This is easy enough, since it lets me "reuse" previous settings -- all I have to change is the Title, date, and time.  But I would love to figure out a way to automate that part of the process, as well.  I assume it involves using the YouTube Data API, but I'm not well versed in API's, JSON, etc.
(I do have a strong Linux background, bash scripting skills, and general programming background.)

My final solution just needs to:

- create the new scheduled event (maybe 12 hours prior to going live), with Title, Date, Time, "Unlisted" status, category, and so forth -- all the usual settings I do manually within Studio
- retrieve the assigned URL for the upcoming stream (my script will then email that to me)

So, basically, I'm asking for help getting started with the API, or whatever method is capable of doing this.  I would prefer to code it on the same Pi that does the ffmpeg encoding (although in a pinch, I could create the schedule from another computer, even Windows).  Any examples would be great.

So far, all I have done is create my Google project, enable the YouTube Data API in the project, and create my API key.  But I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Did you actually read the docs - [Live Streaming API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started)?

Comment: @HTF ("Did you actually...")  Was that really necessary?  I wasn't asking for someone to do all the work for me -- I was just asking for a nudge in the right direction, i.e. "what" to read.  I'm a retired guy, not someone who has been trained in modern coding.  But stvar provided more than enough to get me going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Python as implementation language suites you, then I'd recommend to use the Google's [APIs Client Library for Python](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client).

Basically, this library is of good quality and (compared to other client libraries) simple to use. It will, for example, insulate you from having to deal explicitly with REST API calls, JSON and the like. Your code will also work under both GNU/Linux and Windows.

You may begin your journey by reading the official getting started doc: [YouTube Live Streaming API Overview](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started). Then I recommend absorbing these two important documents: [Life of a Broadcast](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/life-of-a-broadcast) and [Understanding Broadcasts and Streams](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/broadcasts-and-streams).

Then go read, understand and run the following sample program from Google: [`create_broadcast.py`](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/create_broadcast.py). Of course, you'll have to adapt that code to your use case.

You'll have to exercise patience and perseverance (since you say you have no prior experience using the YouTube Data API). This API is non-trivial, but it'll pay off to you at the end of your (programming) journey (you mentioned to be versed in programming).

A special mention: for to be able to call the live streaming APIs you will first need to get acquainted with the things related to the so-called OAuth 2.0 authorization and authentication: [Implementing OAuth 2.0 Authentication](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/authentication). There's an official document that you need absorb: [OAuth 2.0 for Mobile & Desktop Apps](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps).

A few more references: the live streaming API has an [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/) too. The main site documenting the client library is: [Google API Client Library for Python Docs](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/). Its source is public, to be found within the [client library's public repo](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/) under the directory [`docs`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs).

Also useful is to see the [YouTube Data API's list of all instance methods](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/youtube_v3.html).

Comment: @Dale Wellman: Please post comments below, if needing further help and/or clarifications.

Comment: Thank you!  That should be plenty to get me going.  I didn't mention earlier, but I'm a retired guy, so most of my skills are "legacy," as they say.  Hence, the new coding is still a little fuzzy for me.  I just needed to know "what" to read, and you have provided great info here.  If I have further questions later, I'll let you know.  Thanks again!